# Java ArrayList keeps repeating values till end of array

Tags: java, mysql, loops, arraylist

I want to loop trough an ArrayList with the following code. I got a loop and all the parameters are shown. But it is repeating itself untill the end of the sql database.

```
ArrayList<Ews> controles = new ArrayList<>(); 
    try {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + database + ".controle";
        java.sql.Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            int id = rs.getInt("id");
            if (nr == id) {   
                Ews x = new Ews(rs.getString("datum"), rs.getInt("systole"), rs.getInt("diastole"), + 
                rs.getInt("pols"), rs.getDouble("temperatuur"));                 
                controles.add(x);
                Integer i = 1;
                for (Ews controle : controles) {
                    System.out.println(i  + ") " + controle.getDate() + 
                    " - Bloeddruk: " + controle.getSyst() + "/" + controle.getDiast() +
                    " - Pols: " + controle.getPulse() + " - Temperatuur: " + controle.getTemp());
                    i++;
                }
            }
        } 
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I got this result.

```
    1)  - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 38.0
1)  - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 38.0
2)  - Bloeddruk: 130/60 - Pols: 32 - Temperatuur: 38.0
1)  - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 38.0
2)  - Bloeddruk: 130/60 - Pols: 32 - Temperatuur: 38.0
3)  - Bloeddruk: 123/60 - Pols: 89 - Temperatuur: 38.0
1)  - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 38.0
2)  - Bloeddruk: 130/60 - Pols: 32 - Temperatuur: 38.0
3)  - Bloeddruk: 123/60 - Pols: 89 - Temperatuur: 38.0
4) null - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 36.0
1)  - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 38.0
2)  - Bloeddruk: 130/60 - Pols: 32 - Temperatuur: 38.0
3)  - Bloeddruk: 123/60 - Pols: 89 - Temperatuur: 38.0
4) null - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 36.0
5) 24-11-2020 13:12 - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 61 - Temperatuur: 36.0
1)  - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 38.0
2)  - Bloeddruk: 130/60 - Pols: 32 - Temperatuur: 38.0
3)  - Bloeddruk: 123/60 - Pols: 89 - Temperatuur: 38.0
4) null - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 36.0
5) 24-11-2020 13:12 - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 61 - Temperatuur: 36.0
6) 24-11-2020 13:16 - Bloeddruk: 160/61 - Pols: 68 - Temperatuur: 36.0

// And so on...
```

But i wanted this result

```
1)  - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 38.0
2)  - Bloeddruk: 130/60 - Pols: 32 - Temperatuur: 38.0
3)  - Bloeddruk: 123/60 - Pols: 89 - Temperatuur: 38.0
4) null - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 60 - Temperatuur: 36.0
5) 24-11-2020 13:12 - Bloeddruk: 120/60 - Pols: 61 - Temperatuur: 36.0
6) 24-11-2020 13:16 - Bloeddruk: 160/61 - Pols: 68 - Temperatuur: 36.0

// and so on...
```

I hope you guys understand my problem and know how to fix it:)

Comment: Could you please add what is `nr` in your code and why you are using i as an increment variable?

Comment: Move your `for` loop outside of the `while` loop.

Comment: nr is the variable that needs to be equal with ID. I want to show some results of patient (in a hospital) depending on his ID. nr is declared as argument in the method.
i as increment is there to give the results a number (just voor simplicity in reading)

@ GriffeyDog, thanks. That worked, thought i tried everything, guess not, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you building up your list and then iterating over it. You need to finish building out your list first, then look to iterate with the outputs.

```
while (rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getInt("id");
        if (nr == id) {   
            Ews x = new Ews(rs.getString("datum"), rs.getInt("systole"), rs.getInt("diastole"), + 
            rs.getInt("pols"), rs.getDouble("temperatuur"));                 
            controles.add(x);
       }
}

Integer i = 1;
for (Ews controle : controles) {
     System.out.println(i  + ") " + controle.getDate() + 
     " - Bloeddruk: " + controle.getSyst() + "/" + controle.getDiast() +
     " - Pols: " + controle.getPulse() + " - Temperatuur: " + controle.getTemp());
     i++;
}
```

The above purely answers your looping problem hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Move your for loop outside of the while loop.

Thanks @GriffeyDog